# Unexpected output of nested Dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, firebase, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary `X` of type `[ String : Double ]` and I am trying to embed this to inside another dictionary called `dictArray: [ Int : [String: Double] ]`

```
for (index, element) in hide.vertices.enumerate(){
            dictArray[index] =  HiddenLatlng(lat: element.latitude, lng: element.longitude).toDictionery() 
        }
```

here, `toDictionery` method of class `HiddenLatlng` returns the dictionary of type `X` .

I am trying to embedded this `dictArray` inside another dictionary

```
dict = [String: AnyObject]()

dict["eventLatLngList"] = dictArray
```

But when I print `dict`

It shows

```
dictionary is ["eventLatLngList": {
    0 =     {
        latitude = "27.68837718075604";
        longitude = "85.31910706311464";
    };
    3 =     {
        latitude = "27.68837718075604";
        longitude = "85.31910706311464";
    };
    1 =     {
        latitude = "27.69259521229669";
        longitude = "85.31552363187075";
    };
    2 =     {
        latitude = "27.68497603665675";
        longitude = "85.31393576413393";
    };
}]
```

But My expection was:

```
dictionary is ["eventLatLngList": [
    0 :     [
        "latitude" : 27.68837718075604,
        "longitude" : 85.31910706311464
    ],
    3 :    [
        "latitude" : 27.68837718075604,
        "longitude" : 85.31910706311464
    ],
    1 :     [
        "latitude" : 27.69259521229669,
        "longitude" : 85.31552363187075
    },
    2 :     [
        "latitude" : 27.68497603665675,
        "longitude" : 85.31393576413393
    ]]
```

I cannot figure out what is causing this weird behaviour ? I am using swift 2.2 with xcode 7.3

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to save array of coordinates to firebase along with some information related with these coordinates.

right after `dict["eventLatLngList"] = dictArray`

I save it to firebase:

```
reference.child("Events").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(dict) { (error: NSError?, reference: FIRDatabaseReference) in
            print("hides saved to firebase") // execution does not enter this closure
            if error != nil {
                print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }else {
                print("information saved.")
            }
            
        }
```

but my app is crashing without any error at this point. I have no idea why it is crashing.

if I do not add `dictArray` to `dict` all information are bieng saved to firebase as it should be.

**Also**, I tested it with a dummy dictionary

```
var testDict = [ "school": ["class" : ["student" : "name"]]]
```

if I add `testDict` to `dict`, It is being saved to firebase as expected.

**update:**
The captured stack trace is:

```
>     * thread #1: tid = 0x47921, 0x016bdbe0 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_bridgeNonVerbatimFromObjectiveC + 196, queue
> = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)
>       * frame #0: 0x016bdbe0 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_bridgeNonVerbatimFromObjectiveC + 196
>         frame #1: 0x0152034c libswiftCore.dylib`Swift._forceBridgeFromObjectiveC <A>
> (Swift.AnyObject, A.Type) -> A + 404
>         frame #2: 0x015888fc libswiftCore.dylib`Swift._NativeDictionaryStorageOwner.bridgingObjectForKey
> (Swift.AnyObject) -> Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject> + 128
>         frame #3: 0x01588868 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift._NativeDictionaryStorageOwner.objectForKey
> (Swift.AnyObject) -> Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject> + 32
>         frame #4: 0x01588a70 libswiftCore.dylib`@objc Swift._NativeDictionaryStorageOwner.objectForKey (Swift.AnyObject) ->
> Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject> + 40
>         frame #5: 0x002601cc Hiidden`+[FSnapshotUtilities internalNodeFrom:priority:withValidationFrom:atDepth:path:](self=<unavailable>,
> _cmd=<unavailable>, val=<unavailable>, aPriority=<unavailable>, fn=@"updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock:", depth=<unavailable>,
> path=@"0 elements") + 340 at FSnapshotUtilities.m:61
>         frame #6: 0x00260042 Hiidden`+[FSnapshotUtilities nodeFrom:priority:withValidationFrom:atDepth:path:](self=<unavailable>,
> _cmd=<unavailable>, val=<unavailable>, aPriority=<unavailable>, fn=@"updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock:", depth=0, path=@"0
> elements") + 90 at FSnapshotUtilities.m:33
>         frame #7: 0x0025ffb6 Hiidden`+[FSnapshotUtilities nodeFrom:priority:withValidationFrom:](self=<unavailable>,
> _cmd=<unavailable>, val=<unavailable>, priority=<unavailable>, fn=@"updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock:") + 130 at
> FSnapshotUtilities.m:28
>         frame #8: 0x0025ff1a Hiidden`+[FSnapshotUtilities nodeFrom:withValidationFrom:](self=<unavailable>, _cmd=<unavailable>,
> val=<unavailable>, fn=@"updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock:") + 50
> at FSnapshotUtilities.m:24
>         frame #9: 0x00260da8 Hiidden`+[FSnapshotUtilities compoundWriteFromDictionary:withValidationFrom:](self=<unavailable>,
> _cmd=<unavailable>, values=<unavailable>, fn=<unavailable>) + 424 at FSnapshotUtilities.m:161
>         frame #10: 0x00289a26 Hiidden`-[FIRDatabaseReference updateChildValuesInternal:withCompletionBlock:from:](self=<unavailable>,
> _cmd=<unavailable>, values=<unavailable>, block=(Hiidden`reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@owned
> Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSError>, @owned __ObjC.FIRDatabaseReference) ->
> (@unowned ()) to @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned
> Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSError>, @unowned __ObjC.FIRDatabaseReference)
> -> (@unowned ()) at FRecord.swift), fn=@"updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock:") + 142 at
> FIRDatabaseReference.m:185
>         frame #11: 0x0028998c Hiidden`-[FIRDatabaseReference updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock:](self=0x167ecf90,
> _cmd=<unavailable>, values=<unavailable>, block=<unavailable>) + 52 at FIRDatabaseReference.m:179
>         frame #12: 0x000c6330 Hiidden`FRecord.save(hide=Hiidden.Hide @ 0x00fde6c8, completion=0x0006c8ec Hiidden`Hiidden.HideViewModel.(save
> () -> ()).(closure #1) at HideViewModel.swift:39, self=0x1ae54500) ->
> ()) -> () + 4108 at FRecord.swift:116
>         frame #13: 0x000697f8 Hiidden`HideViewModel.save(self=0x173529c8) -> () + 1432 at
> HideViewModel.swift:43
>         frame #14: 0x001a08fc Hiidden`MessageViewController.btnSave(sender=0x1abee640,
> self=0x17352800) -> () + 4732 at MessageViewController.swift:77
>         frame #15: 0x001a0a4c Hiidden`@objc MessageViewController.btnSave(UIBarButtonItem) -> () + 100 at
> MessageViewController.swift:0
>         frame #16: 0x275f76a0 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
>         frame #17: 0x2777a0b8 UIKit`-[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 140
>         frame #18: 0x275f76a0 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
>         frame #19: 0x275f7630 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 64
>         frame #20: 0x275df56a UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 466
>         frame #21: 0x275df696 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 766
>         frame #22: 0x275f6f50 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 616
>         frame #23: 0x275f6bbe UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 646
>         frame #24: 0x275ef546 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 642
>         frame #25: 0x275bfdd4 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 204
>         frame #26: 0x324d751a UIKit`-[UIApplicationAccessibility sendEvent:] + 62
>         frame #27: 0x275be378 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5016
>         frame #28: 0x22fa39e6 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
> + 14
>         frame #29: 0x22fa35d6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
>         frame #30: 0x22fa193e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 806
>         frame #31: 0x22ef01c8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
>         frame #32: 0x22eeffbc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
>         frame #33: 0x2450caf8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 160
>         frame #34: 0x27628434 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 144
>         frame #35: 0x001cd098 Hiidden`main + 172 at AppDelegate.swift:23
>         frame #36: 0x22b9c872 libdyld.dylib`start + 2
```

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: Ignoring the print formatting, is there any problem with how it behaves?

Comment: Don't judge what an object is by the way it is *printed*. Test the object itself, its identity, its behavior, not its looks (the representation can - and does - change with different printing tools, like print/NSLog/dump).

Comment: I have updated my question with further information.

Comment: When it crashes, capture the stack trace and include it in the question.  (Type "bt" at the (lldb) prompt in the debug console.)

Comment: can you update your expected output as there are : and = intermixed so it's not clear what the expectation is.

Comment: @Jay: I think expected output is nested dictionary with ":" but it appears that compiler replaces that ":" with "=".

Comment: Can you clarify what 'weird behavior' means in this use case? It's not immediately obvious what the issue is. Also, the likely crash is that dict is malformed in updateChildValues(dict).